# Every key's value is replaced with the value of the last key in my HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'll keep this short and sweet. I am working on a project that involves HashMap nesting, and I'm running into this issue (simplified into a test case):

```
HashMap options = new HashMap();
HashMap<String,String[]> adMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();
String[] Test = new String[2];
Test[0] = "Oh";
Test[1] = "yeah";
adMap.put("Test1",Test);
Test[0] = "Foo";
Test[1] = "Bar";
adMap.put("Test2",Test);
Test[0] = "Foosa";
Test[1] = "Barsa";
adMap.put("Test3",Test);
options.put("adList",adMap);
HashMap<String,String[]> adList = (HashMap<String,String[]>)options.get("adList");
String[] ipPort = adList.get("Test1");
System.out.println(ipPort[0]+ipPort[1]);
```

Expected output: Ohyeah
Real output: FoosaBarsa

Any idea why that's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: You change the value in the already stored objects, you need to make a new reference to the Array object like so:
String[] test = new String[2];
test[0] = ... test[1] = ...
put(...,test)
test = new String[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are updating the same reference of `Test` String array:

```
Test[0] = "Oh";
Test[1] = "yeah";
adMap.put("Test1",Test);
Test[0] = "Foo";
Test[1] = "Bar";
adMap.put("Test2",Test);
Test[0] = "Foosa";
Test[1] = "Barsa";
```

You need to create new array object before pushing into the map. Test with this modification:

```
String[] Test = new String[2];
Test[0] = "Oh";
Test[1] = "yeah";
adMap.put("Test1",Test);

Test = new String[2];
Test[0] = "Foo";
Test[1] = "Bar";
adMap.put("Test2",Test);

Test = new String[2];
Test[0] = "Foosa";
Test[1] = "Barsa";
adMap.put("Test3",Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays are objects, and so have references that are passed around. When you add `Test` to the map, any edits you make (e.g. `Test[0] = "Foo"`) affect that array itself.

Construct and add a new array each time.